# Connect as "root" but write as "apache" with samba and some configuration tips

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, samba

I have a VMware virtual machine running CentOS 6.5 and I have installed `samba.x86_64 0:3.6.9-168.el6_5` package for sharing resources between virtual machine and host (Windows 7 in my case). I have a few question regarding this topic:

1. I don't know if the only package I need is the one I have installed, I need something else?
2. It's possible to connect to `/var/www/html` path as `root` user and write as `apache` user?  I'm trying to avoid the use of this commands any time I upload a file by using programs like SCP in Windows.

   `find /var/www/html -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755`

   `find /var/www/html -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644`

   `find /var/www/html -print0 | xargs -0 chown apache:root`
3. It's possible to create directories as `0755` and files as `0644`?
4. I'm trying to connect from Windows by using `root` user but can't, what I miss?

This is how my config looks like:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Devserver %v
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam


[data]
    comment = Web Server Root Directory
    path = /var/www/html
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    create mask = 0755
    create mode = 0755
    directory mode = 0755
    valid users = root, apache
    force user = root
    force group = root
```

**Some additions**

This is the config I have:

```
[data]
    comment = Web Server Root Directory
    path = /var/www/html
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    create mask = 0664
    force create mode = 0664
    security mask = 0664
    force security mode = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
    force directory mode = 0775
    directory security mask = 0775
    force directory security mode = 0775
    write list = apache 
    valid users = root
    force user = apache
    force group = root
```

It's right or I need to get out some lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have all the necessary packages installed.

For questions 2 and 3 the following should do the trick:

```
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = apache
force group = root
```

The parameter explanations from [SAMBA documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html) tell that `create mode` is just another way of saying `create mask`, so that's redundant. Same goes with `directory mode` which is also synonymous to `directory mask`.

For question 4 to be answered I guess more information might be helpful. For example: Have you entered a password for the root with `smbpasswd` (probably you have, but that's an obvious starting point)? What do you get in SAMBA log files after/during a connection attempt fails?

Comment: Nevermind about question 4 since was my mistake I forget to run `useradd` command for add root to SMB users, can you take a look to my edition and tell me if I need to get out some lines I mean if my config is right or not